# Шаблоны WordPress после активации не соответствуют демо версии

Tags: wordpress

Загрузил на хостинг последнюю версию WP 6.0.2. Далее через раздел "Внешний вид" установил и активировал бесплатную тему Astra. При переходе на главную страницу видны изменения в структуре сайта, но внешний вид полностью голый, возникает чувство что не подгружаются css стили и изображения.

Как выглядит тема в превью:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как выглядит тема после установки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На одном из [ресурсов](https://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/10-rasprostranennyh-problem-s-temami-wordpress-i-puti-ih-resheniya.html) (глава 3) прочитал, что нужно в настройках задать главную страницу - выполнил, а потом для главной страницы применить шаблон разработчика, но в редакторе старицы, выбор шаблона отсутствует (редактор страницы wp 6.0.2 отличается от того, что описано на ресурсе).

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: стили как-то сильно похожи на дефолтные...может там для конкретной страницы шаблон указан?

Comment: Уже была создана тестовая страница, я установил ее как главной. Далее полез редактировать страницу, но там ни где нет свойства с помощью которого можно применить шаблон.

Скрин из редактора:
https://ibb.co/GxkXRdQ

Comment: В атрибутах страницы смотрели? Выбор шаблона страницы должен быть там. Так-то статья на которую Вы ссылаетесь, судя по скринам интерфейса не слишком актуальна, хоть и написано что редактировалась 4 недели назад.

Comment: Да, там ничего полезного. Скрин:
https://ibb.co/zQBF051

Comment: установи плагины которые предлагает тема и должен быть импорт данных

Comment: Плагины не предлагает установить, по поводу импорта данных не понял.

Comment: То что Вы установили тему, не добавляет на сайт контент/текст/картинки и все остальное.

Comment: @Dias, Не понимаю как "ошибка импорта данных" связана с моим вопросом, если я тему устанавливаю через магазин WP (Внешний вид - Добавить - и выбираю из списка предложенных), а не импортирую через "Загрузить тему"

Comment: @Simon, а какой тогда вообще смысл от этой огромной библиотеки тем WP, если после установки любой из них, мы получаем голый сайт без контента?

Comment: Это факт, и не важно видится Вам в этом смысл или нет, тем более вопрос не ко мне. Это так работает и не только в WordPress а и в остальных движках, так как обычно контент на сайте уникальный, а тема -- всего лишь инструмент для визуального оформления контента, потому импорт данных опционален, если разработчик темы вообще предоставляет такую опциию, как демо контент и его импорт. Погуглил за Вас: [How to Install & Import Demo Data in Astra Theme | 2022 New Update | Astra WordPress Theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4G8gGWO0-w&ab_channel=RbnWebSolutions)

Comment: Контент - это полностью твоя забота. (Да и зачем кому-то на сайте чужой контент, да на иностранном языке?) А тема - это внешний вид, а не наполнение сайта.

Comment: @Simon, благодарю за развернутый ответ! Отдельное спасибо за видео, там разбирается метод, как можно установить плагин Starter Tempaltes ([тут инструкция](https://wpastra.com/resources/elementor-templates-free-downloads/)), с помощью которого как раз можно и установить готовые шаблоны с наполнением.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

На демках *любой* темы показано как сайт **может** выглядеть *после настройки*. Никто не обещает "достаточно установить тему и всё будет как ты себе представляешь".

Но в Астре, как и во многих других темах, есть возможность установить **демоконтент** и соответствующие ему настройки. Для этого прямо из настроек темы нужно установить плагин импорта стартовых шаблонов и выбрать понравившийся.

[image]

Comment: Спасибо! Чуть ранее получил ответ на свой вопрос, Ваш ответ подтверждает правильность действий)